# Border.Background Effect

Tags: wpf

I have been trying Microsoft.Expression.Media.Effects to create a MonoChromeEffect on UIElements.

xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects"

```
<Border.Effect>
      <e: MonochromeEffect  Color="Blue" />
</Border.Effect>
```

This works fine for any control with any Color.

My problem is when attempting to apply to an ImageBrush. (adding blue mono-tint to just the background).

```
  <Border.Background >
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding WaterMarkImage}"
        Stretch="UniformToFill" Opacity=".34"
        RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" 
        AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Top" />
  </Border.Background>
```

This will colorize all controls inside the Border - (including for instance - ListBoxItems to mono-blue).

Is there anyway to just affect just the ImageBrush - (not the list items - (keep them White)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a VisualBrush with an Image control instead of an ImageBrush and apply the effect to the Image:

```
<Border.Background>
    <VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Image ImageSource="{Binding WaterMarkImage}"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill" Opacity=".34" ...>
                <Image.Effect>
                    <e:MonochromeEffect Color="Blue"/>
                </Image.Effect>
            </Image>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Border.Background>
```